# okhttp: IllegalArgumentException: Unexpected char 0xea

Tags: android, http, http-headers, okhttp

I am sending Latin character as HTTP header from my android code using okhttp

```
Builder builder=new Builder();
builder.url(myURL);
builder.addHeader("Original-Filename", "tête-à-tête.pdf");
```

But, I am getting `IllegalArgumentException: Unexpected char 0xea` at 1

I am able to send the same header from Postman or by using `HttpsURLConnection`. Also, the character is an excepted header format as per [HTTP1.1 documentation](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.2.4).

So, then why is okHttp not supporting the following character? Also, is there any workaround this without changing code on the server-side by doing Base64 encoding and decoding.

I am using okttp version 4.4.0. Also, I have already gone through https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/2016 before anyone repeats the same thing.

Comment: encode the string and then add to header

Comment: @Rajnishsuryavanshi that requires server side changes too as I mentioned in my question. I can't do that.

Comment: Did you try `Headers.of()`?

Comment: FWIW, non-ASCII characters in HTTP fields are deprecated and not portable.You may want to have a look at RFC 6266 which defines a way to send file name information in a standard way.

Answer (score 7):

For anyone looking for the answer, I found the answer.

We can use [addUnsafeNonAscii](https://square.github.io/okhttp/4.x/okhttp/okhttp3/-headers/-builder/add-unsafe-non-ascii/) to solve this issue.

Below is the simple code snippet of it

```
Headers headers = new Headers.Builder()
.addUnsafeNonAscii("Original-Filename", "tête-à-tête.pdf")
.build();
```

By doing this we can avoid server-side changes, although in the long term it is suggested to use Base64 encoding on client-side and decoding that on the server-side.

Comment: can you help me integrating this, I'm not to able to identify how and where to add tis headers object with retrofit

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function:

```
 private fun getSafeValue(value: String, defaultValue: String): String {
    for (i in value.indices) {
        val c = value[i]
        if ((c == '\t' || c in '\u0020'..'\u007e').not()) {
            return defaultValue
        }
    }
    return value
}
```

And then:

```
.header("Authorization", getSafeValue(unsafeValue, defaultValue=""))
```